# Async components Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, webpack-2, vue-router, async-components

I'm trying to use async components. Here is my configuration:

1. Vue 2 using Single File Component approach
2. Webpack 2
3. Vue Router

The app is pretty basic, I have an "everyone" section contained in `App` and an "admin" section contained in `Admin`. I would like to load the component and all the `.js` related to the `Admin` if and only if I'm visiting the corresponding route.

After reading the [vue-router docs on Lazy Loading](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html), and the one of Vue2 [on async components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components), I'm still not sure how to do that especially with the ***Single File Component*** approach.

Here is what I did for the moment but I don't know if it is ok since in the documentation of Vue2 they said :

```
Vue.component(
  'async-webpack-example',
  () => import('./my-async-component')
)
```

Also what do I have to do with webpack so it creates a chunk of everything related to `Admin` so that `adminChunk.js`is just loaded when reaching admin route ?

What is the syntax to make a single file component a async component ?

#### app.js

```
const Admin = resolve => {
    // require.ensure is Webpack's special syntax for a code-split point.
    require.ensure(['./components/admin/Admin.vue'], () => {
        resolve(require('./components/admin/Admin.vue'))
    })
};

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: App },
    { path: '/admin', meta: { requiresAdmin: true }, component: Admin},
];
```

#### Admin.vue

```
<template>
        <admin-menu></admin-menu>
        <child></child>
</template>


<script>
    import AdminMenu from './Admin-Menu.vue'
    import Child from './child.vue
    
    export default{
        data () {
        },
        components: {
            AdminMenu,
            Child,
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey hey, i do SSR in vue 2 and have it the same as with your Admin.vue and app.js.  It is the require.ensure that allows you to lazy load them.  Any chance you could put up a JS fiddle with example on this to dig further in it?

Comment: You right it is actually already working since webpack is detecting the code and creates automatically the chunk. The name of the chunk is 0.js, would you know by any chance how to specify the name ? So it could be sonething like admin.js

Comment: After some hours of trying the official Vue docs on splitting async components with Webpack this is the really working solution. Thanks guys. Just an addition: the first argument to `require.ensure()` can be an empty array `[]`. No need to duplicate there the file you `require()` within `resolve()`. Here is [Webpack `require.ensure()` official docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods#requireensure) just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a third parameter to the `require.ensure` function with the name of the chunk.